# A solution to a Graph algorithm required

Tags: algorithm, graph

Question:

Find the minimum number of airplanes required for an airplane operator,given schedule of all flights.

So given a schedule (source, destination, departure time, duration of journey) of all flights, we need to find minimum number of airplanes the operator need.

When an airplane completes a trip. It takes at least 50 mins to start another trip.

Edit: I was unable to come up with a solution..

I tried making a graph with each trip as a node..and there is a directed edge between first node to second node if destination of first node is same as source of second node and start time of second node is 50 mims after completion of journey of first node.

any help would be appreciated on how to proceed..

Note: I was asked this question at an interview at Microsoft.

Comment: So what is your own answer?

Comment: Cool! Do you also have a question for us or are you just boasting with the cool question you got.

Comment: I was unable to answer it .. thats why asked here to find a solution

Comment: @abhinav that's not how stackoverflow works. You have to show some effort, show what you have done and where you are stuck and only then ask for help on that specific aspect of the task. We are not here to solve your problems for you.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev .... I posted it here to get a solution...i dont know how to solve it

Comment: In absence of a full correct solution, did you make *any* start or headway on the problem?

Comment: I think there is something missing in the question: as is, it sounds too simple as there is no real interaction possible (see pjotr's answer). If you are allowed to fly planes between locations out of the schedule, then the flight duration matrix has to be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undestood you right, there are start city, finish-city, and we need to find way with minimum flights to reach destination city from start city. Is that ok?

How I see solution with dynamical programming, lets in `dp[i][j]` will be  stored best time we can get to reach city with number `i` using only `j` flights.
At beginning all elements of `dp` is set to `infinity`. We will try to update it on each step.
So, algorithm will be smth like this below :

```
    dp[0][0] = 0;
    priority_queue< pair<int,int> >  q;
    q.Add( make_pair(0,0) );
    /*in q we store pair, where first is time of arrival in city,
        and the second is THAT city.*/


        while there are element is queue {
           x = the first one element ( where time is the smallest )
           remove first element from queue
            if x.city == destination city 
                 break cycle;
           then 
              for all j
                 if dp[x.city][j] < x.time + 50 
                     for all flights(from, to) where from==x.city we try to update
                         if( dp[to][j+1] < dp[x.city][j] + 50 + jurney_duration ) {
                             dp[to][j+1] = dp[x.city][j] + 50 + jurney_duration ;
                            q.add( make_pair(dp[x.city][j] + 50 + jurney_duration, to) );
                      }
              }
```

so, to find answers, we only need to find the smallest `x` where `dp[final_dest][x] != infinity`, and this `x` will be the answer.

The efficiency will be `O(n*n*m)` , because the body of `while-cycle` we will run only `n` times ( where `n - number of cities` ), and cycle has two cycles of `n` and `m`.
We will run first `for-cycle` only n times, because the path will use less than `N` flights - there are no reason to get back to city where you was before.

**EDIT:** 
Actually, if we will store information of flights like [Adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) we can get efficiency even better : O(n*m), because, for example, if city with number `i` is adjacent to m<sub>i</sub>, we will get N*m<sub>0</sub> + N*m<sub>1</sub> + ... + N*m<sub>N</sub> = N*(m<sub>0</sub> + m<sub>1</sub> + ... + m<sub>n</sub>) = N*M, because sum of m<sub>i</sub> th == M. (M stands for the total number of flights).
[More details about priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)

Comment: DP should be filled  "dp[to][j+1] = x.time + 50 + x.jurney_duration". Your should check "dp[x.city][j] < x.time" as 50 already added to DP value.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is stated, it's actually pretty straightforward.

```
Order the flight list by the departure time. 
Start with 0 planes.
For every flight, 
  look if there's a plane available at the source at the time of departure
  If yes, select it, else add a new plane and select it.
  Mark the plane as available at the destination at time of arrival + preparation
Return # of planes used
```

#### Notes

- This algorithm doesn't allow planes to make another flights than those in the schedule, that's how I understand the question. If that were allowed, this greedy solution wouldn't work anymore.
- This is easy because it's far from a real world situation. If e.g. price and capacity are introduced to the problem, it gets much trickier

Comment: A note on your first note: that alone makes the problem much more complicated as all planes are no longer interchangeable and you have an actual choice to make about which plane to get flown in.

Comment: @Khaur True, with that change this solution won't help. Thanks for the correction.